Los dato no se muestran en el jTable
Estoy haciendo un proyecto pero me pasa los siguiente, no se muestran los datos en el jtable, solo se muestra en blanco:

Este es el código que uso para cargar los datos:
frm_DistribucionMaquila frmDM = new frm_DistribucionMaquila(null, true);
    frmDM.setTitle("Distribución pares.");
    frmDM.setVisible(true);
    
    if(!"".equals(frmDM.getInformation()))
    {
        //LimpiarTabla();
        
        for(TablaDetalle td : frmDM.detallePedido)
        {
            Object[] fila = {
                td.getPedido(),
                td.getModelo(),
                td.getColor(),
                td.getClaveM(),
                td.getMaterial(),
                td.getPunto(),
                td.getPares()
            };
            
            modeloO.addRow(fila);
        }
        
        CalcularPares();
    }

El DefaultTableModel lo cargo en el constructor del jFrame de la siguiente manera:
private final DefaultTableModel modeloO;

public frm_NOrdenMaquila() 
{
    initComponents();
    
    modeloO = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Ordenes.getModel();
}

Ya lo depure y veo que si captura los datos, pero no los muestra.
Estos son los datos que se guardan en la variable fila:

Pero no me los muestra en la tabla.

Hola. ¿Puedes mostrar cómo creas jt_Ordenes? ¿Le estás creando las columnas correspondientes?

jt_Ordenes es el nombre de la tabla que muestro en la primera imagen

Sí pero cómo creas el objeto. Pulsa en [edit] para agregar esa parte del código. Es relevante para determinar el problema.

Si te refieres a la tabla, solamente la tomo de la caja de herramientas o paleta y la arrastro al formulario, las columnas las creo desde la opción "Table contents"

Me refiero a que tú tienes un objeto llamado jt_Ordenes, y estás creando modeloO a partir de ese objeto en esta llamada: modeloO = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Ordenes.getModel(); ¿De dónde sale jt_Ordenes? Muestra el código donde lo creas. No me refiero a la captura de pantalla, que puede corresponder a eso o a otra cosa. El problema está en el código, debes mostrar los objetos implicados.

No, mira jt_Ordenes es el nombre del jTable, el modeloO lo declaro antes del constructor de la siguiente manera: "private final DefaultTableModel modeloO;". Es decir jt_Ordenes no lo creo mediante código simplemente lo arrastro desde la paleta de controles

En la pregunta dices: El DefaultTableModel lo cargo en el constructor del jFrame de la siguiente manera: modeloO = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Ordenes.getModel(); ¿Ves que ahí hay un objeto que se llama jt_Ordenes y que estás invocando getModel() sobre ese objeto para crear a modeloO? Entonces, vete al constructor del JFramey revisa cómo se declara jt_Ordenes.

Ya modifique, la parte donde pongo esa linea, lo raro es que en los otros frames, también lo hago así, y me muestra los datos sin problemas

En el código compartido sigue sin verse donde inicializas a jt_Ordenes. Debes comprender tu código, si no te va a ser difícil depurar errores. Mira qué ocurre en el método initComponents() que estás llamando antes de asignar a modeloO, quizá ahí está el problema.

Hola Macx, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y adjuntes todo el código de la clase, asi será posible que te ayudemos.
